# Slow connection to DB2 on Cloud Database ( from WildFly server aplication)

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I need some help! Some time ago we migrated an Oracle database to `DB2 on Cloud`.

My application use a WildFly Server and the connection to Oracle database previously only needed 5 minutes to start, that was a normal time to start.

However, when I  start using `DB2 on cloud`, the time to start is about 14 minutes.

Using `IBM Data Server Manager`, I tried to monitor what is happening with the database during the application server connection and I can see a process call "Compilation Process", which is responsible for the time to complete the connection.  I do not understand if that is normal, or if there exists any solution to decrease the time used for that process. Thank you very much !!

Comment: Was the Oracle database *local* (on the same network as Wildfly)?  How does the hardware-resources compare (specifically CPU and RAM)  between the Oracle database, and the `Db2 on cloud` database?

Comment: Hi !! The Oracle database is normally used in the same network as the Wildfly server, defined as the optimal architecture in on-premises networks. In the case of DB2, it is configured as a cloud service, and the Wildfly server that connects to it is also in the cloud, although not as a service, but runs inside a virtual server with Linux. Regarding the hardware properties, it has been tested even with fewer resources in Oracle, it is still faster. Thank you very much

Comment: You need to get skilled experienced troubleshooters to work on this. It is not really for stackoverflow. If your app is mostly dynamic-SQL, then that all needs to be compiled...and the Db2-database has to be correctly __tuned__ to suit the workload (e.g the pckcache and many related tuning variables).  Compilation speed also depends on whether literals or host-variables are mainly being used.  All this is configuration, not programming. That's why you need experienced folks.

Comment: You might want to check first whether the issue is related to network. You can try copying couple of large files from application server to database servers in  both environments and compare results. Also, copy several small files (may be 100) in both environments  and compare results. You can look into database performance after eliminating network as probable cause.